# Token [commerce-order:payment-method-information] does not display anything

Tags: commerce, rules

I 've tried adding a token [commerce-order:payment-method-information] for emails , but the token does not work or does not display anything in the email sent . Please help

[image]

[image]

Comment: What payment method are you using?

Comment: I use Bank Transfer payment method

Comment: Are you using the Bank Transfer payment provided by [Bank Transfer](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bank_transfer) or did you create one using [Commerce Custom Offline Payments](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cop)?

Comment: sorry forget to say, yes I use Bank Transfer payment provided by Commerce Custom Offline Payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. Have you updated removed the text in the **Information** field on the payment's configuration page:
   [image]
2. Do you have a `filtered_html` text-format? Is it configured correctly?
3. If you're not using this in tandem with Commerce Message, you'll need to be using it.